# How can you set the datasource of a combo and set the text value on load

Tags: vb.net

I want to populate combos with the same list of data from the "modules" table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      however, depending on what is in the "completedModules" data table I will set the text value to a particular item on the load.

Setting the data source seems to override the set text value.

```
    With ComboBox1

        .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup
        .ValueMember = modules.Columns("id").ColumnName
        .DisplayMember = modules.Columns(0).ColumnName
        .DataSource = modules
        .Text = completedModules.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString

    End With
```

Comment: Use `.SelectedValue = completedModules.Rows(0).Field<int>("id")`, instead of `Text = ...`

Comment: What's inside `completedModules.Rows(0).Item(0)`? Something that relates to `modules.Columns(0)` or `modules.Columns("id")`?

Comment: It is a value that also exists in modules.column(0). Essentially I am looking to display a text value which has been previously selected on that combo and saved to the database.

Comment: Well, if `completedModules.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString` represents one of the Items included in the `DisplayMember` selection, you can surely set the `ComboBox.Text`. But, IMO, you should probably set the `.SelectedValue` instead, using the `completedModules` column that returns the `ID`. If it's a ValueType (Integer, Long etc.), convert it to the corresponding type. Btw, if you're using a DataTable as the DataSource, you have to use the `DataTable.DefaultView` as the `DataSource` of a ComboBox.